# Program Design clearness vs convenience

Tags: java, design, frameworks

I've recently disputed with my colleague about the following situation:

I've developed a framework that processes the resources (in java, although its not really important). It goes (simplified, pseudo-code) like this:

```
class Algorithm {
    Processor processor = ...;
    execute() {
        forEach(Resource r : readResourceNamesFromFileSystem()) {
           DomainObject do = convertResourceToDomainObject(r);
           processor.process(do);
        }       
    } 

}

interface Processor {
     process(DomainObject do);
}
```

Class **Algorithm** is an entry point to my framework. Resource is a representation of some content in the filesystem (it has methods for reading the data from file and the file name, which is important)

Class **DomainObject** (declaration is omitted) is a java representation of the content of the file depicted by Resource. DomainObject only has data and doesn't have a filename inside.

Class **Processor** represents the business logic layer, the DomainObject can be processed, stored in Database and so forth.

The content data is supplied by others, we just know that these files contain the data that can be converted into DomainObject(s) which is a real object we work with in the framework. We store one DomainObject in one file.

Now we argue about the file name. Colleague of mine wants the file name to be propagated into the Processor and potentially to all the layers because  its easy to print the logging message/throw an exception that contains a file name if something goes wrong during the processing, or maybe to write the message like "domain object stored in file (**here__comes__filename**) has been processed successfully".

I see the point of my colleague (convenience) but I'm sure it breaks the design and encapsulation because the processor module shouldn't really be aware of the "origin" of the DomainObject (today we store them in files one DomainObject per file, tomorrow we'll maybe use something else, something that doesn't necessarily has a filename).

I claim that we better catch the exception in the Algorithm.execute method and rethrow the exception with a filename/ log the filename. The log file will be less readable but the encapsulation won't be broken.

In my understanding its a design vs clearness. Could you please share your opinion, who is right, who is wrong? Should I sacrifice the design for the clearness of logs?

BTW I've promised my colleague to ask this question so we'll read the possible answers together :)

Thanks a lot in advance and have a nice day

Comment: One option would be to add a `source` property to `DomainObject` and set it to the filename when loading from a file. This provides the info your colleague wants without breaking encapsulation or leaking the abstraction too much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Catch the exception at the level where you *do* have the file name, incorporate the file name into the error message, and rethrow.

This is a classic example of why exceptions are designed the way they are; they propagate up the call stack to the next available `catch` clause, where new information can be added to them where it is available.  This avoids the need to pollute your classes by propagating logging information throughout your class hierarchy.

Java will even [maintain the original stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1097527/102937).

The whole point of having things like `stream` objects is to abstract away details like file names.  A `stream` doesn't care where the data it is streaming comes from, and some data sources don't even have file names associated with them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for an answer. 10 points from me for sure :-) I totally agree with you, but please note,its not only about exceptions, but also logging messages from within the processor.

Comment: You can still do that as well, right?

Comment: If there is no exception, than there is no way to know inside the processor class what's the file name is without passing it into context. I think that's the main reason for debate - whether we should pollute the code (design) or keep it clean and live with a situation when the log message doesn't contain the file name

Comment: You can always throw your own exception, y'know.

Comment: If we really have an excpetion then I totally agree with you. Yes, of course I can, but I'm talking about the situation when there is no exception. Instead we have a lot of resources to process so throwing exception and interrupting the flow is kind of "expensive" and I think its wrong.

Comment: Why would you need to know the file name on an error that doesn't warrant an exception?

Comment: I'm not talking an exception flow at all now. Assume you have inside processor a query to the db. My colleague wants to log message __inside__ the processor that looks like this: LOG.info("Querying the database about the resource that was defined in filename " + filename); Now the his statement is that its much easier to read the log in this form and in our domain its indeed probably so. I claim however that it will break the encapsulation and here we have a tradeoff I'm asking about. Thats all. Again, regarding exception flow you totally right

Comment: If you want the filename, you have to pass a message to the logger somehow.  That can take the form of an exception, you can propagate the file name through the object composition layers, you can hand the logger a file name before you start the loop.  There are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a logging framework like Log4j, you can use a nested diagnostic context (NDC) to store the file name at the point it is available, then retrieve from the NDC at the time you log the messages.

[Logj4 NDC](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html)

This can be even more useful because you can actually write a log4j appender that handles log messages specially based on the NDC content.

The specific case I used this was an embedded Jetty web server. Parts of the incoming URI identified the customer e.g.

```
http://domain/app/<customer-name>/otherstuff...
```

The Jetty request dispatcher extracted the value of "customer-name" from the URI and stored it in the Log4j NDC.

It was almost trivial to write a log4j appender that, when the NDC contained a customer name value, appended the message to a .log file.

That way we had a single coherent log file that contained all the diagnostic information in sequence, plus we had logs of activity relevant (and private) to each customer.